# Creating .sd file from .mxd in Python?

Tags: arcpy, mxd, service-definition

How would I save a .sd (service definition) file from an MXD purely with Python? I can create an .sd by stepping through the process and saving as a service definition. However, I'm looking to fully automate my process.

Comment: All the code samples here do it - http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/createmapsddraft.htm#C_GUID-3BCC01E7-A168-4DC1-A715-7B51B3FE3802